# Distribution of sufficient statistic of negative bionomial distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Negative binomial distribution with known parameter k has the following distribution:
$$
f(r;k,p)=\binom{k+r-1}{k}(1-p)^{r}p^k~~~~~\text{for}~r=0,1,2,\ldots
$$
Then the join probability of $n$ Negative binomial independent variables, has distribution:
$$
f(\textbf{r};k,p)=\prod_{i=1}^n\binom{k+ r_i -1}{k}(1-p)^{\sum_{i=1}^{n} r_i}p^{nk} 
$$
Then it can be rewritten in exponential form as:
$$
\begin{align}
    f(k;r,p) &=\prod_{i=1}^n\binom{k+r_i-1}{k}\exp\left[\ln(p^{kn}(1-p)^{^{\sum_{i=1}^{n} r_i}})\right] \\
             &=\prod_{i=1}^n\binom{k+r_i-1}{k}\exp\left[{\ln(1-p)\sum_{i=1}^{n} r_i} + kn\ln(p)\right] \\
\end{align}
$$
From above we can see that the sufficient statistic for $p$ is $$T(\textbf{r}) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} r_i $$

My question is what is the distribution of $r_i$

Comment: Try to generalise the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1054048/negative-binomial-distribution-sum-of-two-random-variables). Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2189105/sum-of-negative-binomial-distributed-r-v.